# Rolling OLS regression and ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, regression

Let's say I have a `df` of stock prices, that look something like this:

```
Date                       Stock A
2019-05-06 07:59:59.999    0.028213
2019-05-06 08:59:59.999    0.028389
2019-05-06 09:59:59.999    0.028242
2019-05-06 10:59:59.999    0.028744
2019-05-06 11:59:59.999    0.028826
2019-05-06 12:59:59.999    0.028949
2019-05-06 13:59:59.999    0.028886
2019-05-06 14:59:59.999    0.028863
2019-05-06 15:59:59.999    0.029398
Name: Stock A, Length: 1000, dtype: float64
```

What I am trying to do for each stock is calculate a predicted value using `ols.PandasRollingOLS(y, X, window=n)` from [`pyfinance`](https://github.com/bsolomon1124/pyfinance), and then calculate how many standard deviations the current price is from the predicted value, and then plot this against some forward returns, i.e. how much the stock went up or down, n number of days in the future, basically `.shift(-n)`. It sounds very simple, but I'm some how getting myself more and more stuck.

The code to run the rolling regression is as follows, and works fine so that's not the issue:

```
X = df['Time']
y = df['Stock A']
model = ols.PandasRollingOLS(y, X, window=250)
prediction = model._predicted
```

`Prediction` then returns 751 arrays with the final number in each array being the number I want to use. So for me to return a list of the predicted value for each data point I have to do `[i[-1] for i in prediction]` which then gives me `[...0.02862762374502103, 0.028612066422311653, 0.028596879968127514, 0.028582598374502034, 0.02856930540239047, 0.028553991394421267, 0.02854553854980154, 0.028536955824703027, 0.028531125290838216, 0.028522397768924877, 0.02851387212749102, 0.028514959521912523]`.

What I want to do first is to be able to create a new column say `df['Diff']` that calculates the difference between the current price and the predicted price then divides by the rolling 100 standard deviation.

My code would be something like `df['Diff'] = (df['Stock A'] - [i[-1] for i in prediction]) / df['Stock A'].rolling(100).std()`

However, that produces `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'generator' and 'float'` as an error, and when I just try to minus one from the other without the standard deviation bit I get, `ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (1000,) (751,)`.

I can understand why I'm getting the error as the price data is 1000 data points long and there are only 751 predictions.

In the end what I want though is 2 columns, one that calculates the difference between current price and predicted price divided by a rolling std, and a second column calculating the percentage forward returns, i.e. `df['returns'] = df['Stock A'].diff(-100)/df['Stock A']`:

```
Date                       Diff     Returns
2019-05-02 07:59:59.999    0.68213  -0.91
2019-05-02 08:59:59.999    0.68389  -0.91
2019-05-02 09:59:59.999    0.68452  -0.92
2019-05-02 10:59:59.999    0.69642  -0.92
2019-05-02 11:59:59.999    0.71459  -0.94
2019-05-02 12:59:59.999    0.73697  -0.96
2019-05-02 13:59:59.999    0.75624  -0.97
2019-05-02 14:59:59.999    0.78542  -0.98
2019-05-02 15:59:59.999    1.20543  -1.25
```

Once I can get this right for one stock I'll just loop through to do it for the rest of them. Any help really appreciated, cheers.

EDIT:

So what I have done is as there is a miss match in the length of the two sets of data, I have written in to cut the price column down to size. What I now have is this:

```
X = data['Time']
y = data['Stock A']
model = ols.PandasRollingOLS(y, X, window=250)
prediction = model._predicted
data['returns'] = (data['Stock A'].shift(-150)-data['Stock A'])/data['Stock A']
data['Stock A'] = data['Stock A'].iloc[-751:]
data['Stock A'].dropna(inplace=True)
data['diff'] = (data['Stock A'] - [i[-1] for i in prediction])/data['Stock A'].rolling(250).std()
```

This essentially does what I want it to do, but the problem I now have is instead of the data starting at data point 250 it starts at 497, so it's cut out half my data points immediately.

If anyone can quickly see what I'm doing wrong, then great, if not don't worry about it, looks like I'll have to abandon this one. Cheers

EDIT 2.0:

Sorry, dropping NA was causing the problem, so I specify the `df` length in the calculations now, so my final code is this, thanks again for help:

```
X = data['Time']
y = data['Stock A']
model = ols.PandasRollingOLS(y, X, window=250)
prediction = model._predicted
data['returns'] = (data['Stock A'].shift(-150)-data['Stock A'])/data['Stock A']
data['diff'] = (data['Stock A'].iloc[-751:] - [i[-1] for i in prediction])/data['Stock A'].rolling(250).std()
```

IN RESPONSE TO BRAD'S COMMENT:

So to begin with I actually get my stock data (144 stocks) from a csv file so you would have to get your data from somewhere, but once you have this is what I was doing.

I wanted to chart/plot a standardised difference between actual and predicted values for each stock, same way you calculate a z-score, and plot that against the forward returns, so say 100 data points in the future, whats the percentage difference. I wanted to see if a price was miles away from its prediction did it really yield a winner over time.

So I calculated the standardised difference and the forward returns, lets say over a 300 point window for the regression, and 400 point window for the returns and then for each stock I appended this data in to a `df`, sorted it by the difference and drop all but the most extreme data points on either side as I would only do a trade if something was well out of line.

```
    df = []
    data['Time'] = range(0, 0+ len(data))
    for stock in stocks:
        X = data['Time']
        y = data[stock]
        model = ols.PandasRollingOLS(y, X, window=300)
        prediction = model._predicted
        data['returns'] = (data[stock].shift(-400) - data[stock]) / data[stock]
        lngth = (1000-300)+1 # the length the data needs to be to match the prediction array, otherwise you encounter an annoying error
        data['diff'] = (data[stock].iloc[-lngth:] - [i[-1] for i in prediction]) / data[stock].rolling(300).std()
        df.append(data[['diff', 'returns']])
    df = pd.concat(df, axis=0)
    df.dropna(inplace=True)
    df.reset_index(inplace=True)
    df = df.drop(['Date'], axis=1)
    df.sort_values('diff', inplace=True)
    size = len(df) * 0.001
    size = size.__round__()
    df = df.drop(df.index[size:-size])
    if len(df) > 0:
        X = df['diff'].values.reshape(-1,1)
        y = df['returns'].values.reshape(-1,1)
        model = LinearRegression()
        model.fit(X,y)
        return model.score(X,y)
```

You can play around with the parameters but what I was looking was a combination that fitted well, and 300 regression window, 400 forward returns, fit quite well after a cursory look. The plot looked like this:

[image]

Given that these are sh1tty high risk stocks I'm looking at that have been murdered in the last few months, being able to even return 0% is actually a bit of a winner, so my conclusion would be it's something worth looking at when doing a trade.

Anyway hope this helps someone one day.

Comment: If you have 1000 data points and 751 predictions, I don't understand what difference you would like to calculate

Comment: The 751 most recent differences.

Comment: So you want to use only the last 751 entries in df['Stock A']?

Comment: Hi mate so you gave me a good idea there, have edited my post, still not really doing what I need it to but I'm halfway there, so thanks for that

Comment: Hi @topbantz, glad to see someone is getting use out of pyfinance!  You've offered a lot of detail here, but it would help if you could create a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that we can follow along better

Comment: Hi mate, tried to post something of an example hope it's what you meant